# How do I replace PATH Environment variable items to double quote those which have spaces?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, bash, path

I am looking for a short command which I can execute in the Windows 10 command shell (`cmd`) or in `powershell` or in `git-bash` for Windows, which would replace `PATH Environment variable` items to double quote those which have spaces?

The actual problem I face is that when I type a command in git-bash

```
$ sfdx force:org:create -s -f config/project-scratch-def.json -a "default scratch org"
```

I receive an error

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

[image]
I think this error happens because `sfdx` tool is located in "C:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\bin" and it should be probably double quoted in path if I am not wrong.

So when I execute `path` command in `cmd` I see

```
D:\Git\SFDX\MySFDXProject>path
PATH=C:\Python27\;C:\Ruby23\bin;C:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\bin
```

so I guess `C:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\bin` should be double quoted in path but I want mass double quote any path items which have spaces in path so that any other command won't fail.

So if my path is `C:\Python27\;C:\Ruby23\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\bin` I want it to be transformed by command into `C:\Python27\;C:\Ruby23\bin;"C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin";"C:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\bin"`
and to be saved in PATH environment variable.

How do I do that?

Comment: PATH uses semicolons as delimiters, so quotation marks are not necessary.  My PATH is filled with lots of folders that contain spaces.  My guess is that there is some other environment variable that needs quotation marks.  I'm not familiar with what "sfdx" is, so I can't help further pinpoint your problem.

Comment: You have a syntax error in your system variable.  To determine which path is causing the problem.  Restore the default system variable value, and one by one, add the additional paths you need.  Be sure you are not reaching the length limit for the variable either.

Comment: Bill is right..  It might be something your sfdx command is doing. Also see https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005b4zQAA  it says to try- `$sfdx force:org:create -f project-scratch-def.json -a MyScratchOrg<ENTER>`

Comment: `bash` does not use the same path format as Windows. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701218/windows-path-to-posix-path-conversion-in-bash

Comment: Ok, when I run that command in default windows "CMD" command line, it works, but when I run that command in "git bash" windows shell, it doesn't work. So I guess if I had every path item member doublequoted, it should have worked

Answer (score 0):

Create a file which changes the path, creates a child process, calls the `sfdx` command in the child process, and prints out the result. For example:

```
// env-change.js
process.env.path=process.env.path.replace(/Program Files/g,'"Program Files"');
const { exec } = require('child_process');

function result(err, stdout, stderr){
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log(stdout);
  console.log(process.env.path);
}

exec('sfdx force:org:create -s -f config/project-scratch-def.json -a "default scratch org"', result);
```

Then run it like so:

```
node env-change.js
```

**References**

- [Child Process | Node.js v11.0.0 Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)
- [Process | Node.js v11.0.0 Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env)